# Remove a header from JAXWS Request

Tags: jax-ws

I have used `jaxws` to generate client stub. when the request goes to server I want to remove a particular soap header from it before it can be passed to server for processing. I have tried to add the `handler chain` but not all my requests goes via the added handler. Is there any other way i can do this. Below is a sample of soap header from request xml. I want to remove the `ExchangeImpersonation` header.

```
<S:Header>
<ExchangeImpersonation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
<ConnectingSID>
<PrimarySmtpAddress>myemail@mysite.com</PrimarySmtpAddress>
</ConnectingSID>
</ExchangeImpersonation>
<MailboxCulture xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">en-US</MailboxCulture>
<RequestServerVersion xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" Version="Exchange2010_SP1"/>
<TimeZoneContext xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
<TimeZoneDefinition Id="Eastern Standard Time"/>
</TimeZoneContext>
</S:Header>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear: Are you currently unable to access the headers in the handler or you want to know why all your requests are not going thru your handler?

Comment: I just want to remove the header. I was thinking to do this through handler but as all my requests are not going through handler, I'm looking for some other way.

Comment: A servlet filter for the context path of your webservice that strips the header from the payload before it hits the JAX-WS Servlet will do the job

Comment: I'm developing a standalone client and I have no access to the server. Then how I can add a servlet filter to context path.